# Cannot insert multiple value from database value form php

Tags: php, mysql

This is the error I get:

> Notice: Undefined index: no_siri in C:\xampp\htdocs\PTG
>   Sistem\penyata.php on line 4
>   Notice: Undefined index: agihan in C:\xampp\htdocs\PTG Sistem\penyata.php on line 6

```
INSERT INTO penyata (no_siri, tarikh, penerangan, jumlah_bayaran)
     VALUES
     ('','2016-01-30 21:57:08','Agihan keuntungan adalah sebanyak %','720')
```

> Notice: Undefined index: 1 in C:\xampp\htdocs\PTG Sistem\penyata.php
>   on line 23

---

### Form:

```
 <form method="get" action="penyata.php">
      <div class="panel-body">
      <table class="table table-striped table-hover">
                    <thead>
                    <tr>

                        <th></th>
                        <th>No Siri</th>
                        <th>Tarikh</th>
                        <th>Nama</th>
                        <th>Bank</th>
                        <th>Akaun Bank</th>
                        <th>Lot</th>
                        <th>Agihan</th>
                        <th>Bayaran</th>

                    </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>';


                        while($rows_client = mysql_fetch_array($bayar_client)){

                            $total_bayar = $rows_client['lot'] * ($bayaran /100);

               echo '<tr>

                        <td><input name="checkbox[]" type="checkbox" id="checkbox[]" value="'.$i++.'" /required></td>
                        <td><input name="no_siri[]" type="text" id="no_siri[]" value="'.$rows_client['no_siri'].'" /disabled></td>
                        <td>'.$rows_client['hari'].'/'.$rows_client['bulan'].'/'.$rows_client['tahun'].'</td>
                        <td>'.$rows_client['nama'].'</td>
                        <td>'.$rows_client['nama_bank'].'</td>
                        <td>'.$rows_client['akaun_bank'].'</td>
                        <td>RM'.$rows_client['lot'].'</td>
                        <td><input name="agihan[]" type="text" id="agihan[]" value="'.$bayaran.'" /disabled>%</td>
                        <td>RM <input name="jumlah_bayaran[]" type="text" id="jumlah_bayaran[]" value="'.$total_bayar.'"></td>

                    </tr>';
                        }
                echo '
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info" name="simpan">
                            <i class="fa fa-database"></i>
                        </button>
                        &nbsp;
                        <button class="btn btn-info" onClick="myFunction()" title="Cetak">
                            <i class="fa fa-print"></i>
                        </button>

                        <script>
                            function myFunction() {
                                    window.print();
                            }
                        </script>



                    </tbody>
                    </form>
```

---

### PHP:

```php
include("dbconn.php");

$no_siri = $_GET['no_siri'];
$agihan = $_GET['agihan'];
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kuala_Lumpur');
$tarikh[] = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', time());
$penerangan[] = "Agihan keuntungan adalah sebanyak ".$agihan."%";
$jumlah_bayaran = $_GET['jumlah_bayaran'];

$add_penyata = "INSERT INTO penyata (no_siri, tarikh, penerangan, jumlah_bayaran) VALUES";

$query_parts = array();
foreach($_GET['checkbox'] as $i){
    //for($x=0; $x<count($i); $x++){
        $query_parts[] = "('{$no_siri[$i]}','{$tarikh[$i]}','{$penerangan[$i]}','{$jumlah_bayaran[$i]}')";
    //}
    echo $add_penyata .= implode(',', $query_parts);
}               
//$result = mysql_query($add_penyata);

//echo $add_penyata;

if($result){
    echo '<script type="text/javascript">window.alert("Rekod Berjaya Disimpan.") </script>';
    echo "<script language='JavaScript'>window.location ='akaun.php'</script>";
}
else{
    echo '<script type="text/javascript">window.alert("Ralat!!!!.") </script>';
}
```

---

I want to insert multiple data from form just like

```
INSERT INTO `penyata`(`id`, `no_siri`, `tarikh`, `penerangan`, `jumlah_bayaran`)
     VALUES
     ([value-1],[value-2],[value-3],[value-4],[value-5]),
     ([value-1],[value-2],[value-3],[value-4],[value-5]),
     and more....
```

but i dont know how to make it on php. Im so appreaciate for any solution. Thanks a lot.

Comment: MySQL is deprecated since PHP 5.5, you should use [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/intro.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/intro.pdo.php) instead. Also take a look at [Medoo](http://medoo.in)

Answer (score 0):

First do:

```
if(! $_GET['no_siri']) {
  $no_siri = $_GET['no_siri'];
}
```

First you must check if value exist.

Comment: This error i get : Notice: Undefined index: no_siri in C:\xampp\htdocs\PTG Sistem\penyata.php on line 4

Notice: Undefined index: no_siri in C:\xampp\htdocs\PTG Sistem\penyata.php on line 5
INSERT INTO penyata (no_siri, tarikh, penerangan, jumlah_bayaran) VALUES('','2016-01-31 09:37:34','Agihan keuntungan adalah sebanyak %','960')
Notice: Undefined index: 1 in C:\xampp\htdocs\PTG Sistem\penyata.php on line 25..

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping:

```
if(isset($_GET['no_siri'])){
      $no_siri = $_GET['no_siri'];
}
```

Comment: This error is get : Notice: Undefined variable: no_siri in C:\xampp\htdocs\PTG Sistem\penyata.php on line 25
INSERT INTO penyata (no_siri, tarikh, penerangan, jumlah_bayaran) VALUES('','2016-01-31 09:45:42','Agihan keuntungan adalah sebanyak %','960')
Notice: Undefined variable: no_siri in C:\xampp\htdocs\PTG Sistem\penyata.php on line 25

Answer (score 0):

Shorter:

```
$no_siri = @$_GET['no_siri'];
```

It leaves `$no_siri` with the value or `null`.  The `@` prevents the error message.

Comment: If it leave the value, then how should i get the data to insert on the table?..For example : INSERT INTO statement (no_siri, date, description, total_payment) VALUES('php1234','2016-01-31 09:45:42','Description 7%','960'), then if the data more than 1 it should be INSERT INTO statement (no_siri, date, description, total_payment) VALUES('no_siri','2016-01-31 09:45:42','Description 7%','960'),('php5678','2016-02-01 09:45:42','Description 10%','1200'),and more for looping insert if there many data displayed.